# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuneiform'

Tags: python, ocr

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

from pyocr import pyocr
from pyocr import builders

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()

tool = tools[0]

langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = langs[0]

txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('test.png'),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)

word_boxes = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('test.png'),
    lang="eng",
    builder=pyocr.builders.WordBoxBuilder()
)

line_and_word_boxes = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('test.png'), lang="fra",
    builder=pyocr.builders.LineBoxBuilder()
)

digits = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('test-digits.png'),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.tesseract.DigitBuilder()
)
```

I am trying to learn OCR and had the library pyocr installed in my system, however, it still throws the error

```
No module named 'cuneiform'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in pyocr version  0.2.0; I upgraded to v0.6 and it works.